# Integrating Exchange with website

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

We are trying to integrate Microsoft Exchange (sync appointments) into our web site (SPA)(Software as a Service), for this we are looking at EWS managed API as the  preferred route, we have the end users email, but we do not want to store there exchange passwords (as they are generally same as users domain password), in such a scenario which is the best approach to take. Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

The preferred way would be to define a new Exchange id for your integration program and allow it impersonation rights for each user whose mailbox you want to examine.  The managed API will allow you to specify an impersonation id on each call.  You authenticate with your program's userid and password, but have the rights within the Exchange store of the user you are impersonating.  Thus you only have to manage a single password for your program and need not know users' passwords.  Setting up the impersonation rights requires some fancy PowerShell commands from the Exchange Admin, but you only do it once.